# Why my object is moving left and up without me clicking anythink?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my character goes left and up without my interference and when i click d and s it goes left and down. I saw this is not mine fault couse i debug.log all my buttons clicked.

```
public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;

    public void Update()
    {
        //not inportant
        foreach (KeyCode vKey in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(vKey))
            {

                Debug.Log(vKey.ToString());

            }
        }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0)
        {
            float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
            float verticalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed;

            Vector3 directionOfMovement = new Vector3(horizontalMovement, verticalMovement, 0);

            gameObject.transform.Translate(directionOfMovement);
        }
```

Comment: If the x,y axis is not zero then you are moving a 0.1f.

Comment: than how to make to horizontal and vertical axis will be set to 0?

Answer (score 1):

If using a controller, or a controller is plugged into your device. You should use a dead zone for the RawInput, because the controller may not center to zero, and could have some small value for the RawAxis.

try changing your conditional to have something like:

```
float rawX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
float rawY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

if(Mathf.Abs(rawX) > 0.05f || Mathf.Abs(rawY) > 0.05f) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: it's not working if i debug.log(Input.GetAxisRaw) Horizontal and Vertical i get value for horizontal -1 and for vertical 1 without touching anything

Comment: Strange, do you have any controller plugged in to the machine?  I did find this thread that talks about controller issues and unity.. it's old, but maybe it's relevant.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/gamepads-and-getaxisraw.67906/

Comment: No i only have mouse pluged in. I'm on laptop

Comment: How about changing to GetAxis instead of GetAxisRaw?

Comment: Also tried only what happend is that there was e little lag after click

Comment: One last thing to check is your Inputs mapping settings.. is there anything strange in there that is setting min/max or range on the axis inputs?

Comment: Okey i solved this i just used Input.GetKey() and worked